# Cron job doesn't output data when using variables in filenames

Tags: bash, cron

```
progrm > output/backup-wp-dbs.$(date +"%F_%H%M%S").txt
```

Cron errors using $(date ...) in the above filename. What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "properly format"? what format is it in?

Comment: Here, read this link:  https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/043

Comment: You are the man! Thx Jetchisel!

Answer (score 0):

Answer here per Jetchisel: mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/043
In summary, we need to escape the %'s in cron.